# How do you mix jQuery and IE CSS hacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I want to set the display property of a div to inline-block. In CSS I would do something like the following:

```
#divid {
    display:inline-block;

    /* And now for IE6 and IE7 */
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

But now suppose I want the ability to change the display property of a div to inline-block dynamically, using plain JavaScript or jQuery. Also suppose I have no idea about the HTML and CSS of the relevant page; I'm just passed the div and I need to change its properties. If I weren't worrying about IE6 and IE7, it's easy:

```
$("#divid").css("display", "inline-block");
```

But trying to handle IE6 and IE7 isn't straightforward. The following doesn't work:

```
$("#divid").css("*display", "inline");
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: As @thirtydot pointed out, this is from the `.animate` method, and isn't applied when doing `.css`.

The best alternative I can think of is to use something similar yourself. You can detect if the inline block elements need the `layout` hack, and depending on that, set the properties.

```
if ( !jQuery.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout ) {
    $("#divid").css("display", "inline-block");
} else {
    $("#divid").css("display", "inline");
    $("#divid").css("zoom", "1");
}
```

-- Old Answer --

jQuery should do it automatically if you just do `$("#divid").css("display", "inline-block");`

From the jQuery [source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js)

```
if ( jQuery.css( this, "display" ) === "inline" &&
        jQuery.css( this, "float" ) === "none" ) {
    if ( !jQuery.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout ) {
        this.style.display = "inline-block";

    } else {
        display = defaultDisplay( this.nodeName );

        // inline-level elements accept inline-block;
        // block-level elements need to be inline with layout
        if ( display === "inline" ) {
            this.style.display = "inline-block";

        } else {
            this.style.display = "inline";
            this.style.zoom = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show which function you found this in. I can only find it inside `.animate()`, not inside `.css()`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L183. Can you verify your answer?

Comment: Hmm well using $("#divid").css("display", "inline-block") does not make a div act like an inline element in IE6 or IE7 (e.g., text directly after the closing tag appears on a new line). I'm using the latest version of jQuery too (1.6.1).

Comment: @thirtydot, Sorry, you are right. I didn't notice that this was only in the `.animate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery to apply a CSS class, and use conditional comments to specify different rules for that class in IE 6 and 7. That would greatly simplify your Javascript.

Comment: I was hoping for a jQuery-only method so I would know how to do it in the context of a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few things wrong with this, but it seems to work ok for me.  Please edit if necessary.  Adding this code somewhere in your javascript will hook into jQuery.css and make IE7 display inline-block correctly.

```
(function($) {
    // first, check to see if cssHooks are supported
    if ( !$.cssHooks ) {
        return;
    }

    $.cssHooks["display"] = {
        get: function( elem, computed, extra ) {
            if($.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout && elem.style.display == 'inline' && elem.style.zoom == '1') {
                return 'inline-block';
            }
            return elem.style.display;
        },
        set: function( elem, value ) {
            try {
                if($.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout && value == 'inline-block') {
                    elem.style.zoom = '1';
                    elem.style.display = 'inline';
                    return;
                }
                elem.style.display = value;
            } catch(e){}
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('selector').css('display', 'inline-block');
```